# Interface method Implementation and passing using ByRef with VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, inheritance, interface

I have a C# interface defined as so:

```
public interface IMenuSecurityService
{
    void SetSecurityFlags(List<MenuItem> items);
}
```

I need to implement this interface in a VB.NET class. When I implement the SetSecurityFlags method with the items parameter passed using ByVal, it compiles.

```
Public Sub SetSecurityFlags(ByVal items As List(Of L1.Common.Model.MenuItem)) Implements IMenuSecurityService.SetSecurityFlags
    ' Do some work
End Sub
```

When I try to implement it with the items parameter passed using ByRef, I get the following compiler error:

> Class 'UserRights' must implement 'Sub SetSecurityFlags(items As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Model.MenuItem))' for interface

```
Public Sub SetSecurityFlags(ByRef items As List(Of L1.Common.Model.MenuItem)) Implements IMenuSecurityService.SetSecurityFlags
    ' Do some work
End Sub
```

I can't seem to figure this one out. Does VB.NET not support this or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a VB vs C# issue - it's an issue of your signature being wrong.

Your method doesn't implement the interface, because the interface method has a by-value parameter, whereas your method has a by-reference parameter. You'll have the same problem if you do it in C#:

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Bar(int x);
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void Bar(ref int x) {}
}
```

Compilation error:

```
Test.cs(8,7): error CS0535: 'Foo' does not implement interface member
    'IFoo.Bar(int)'
```

You haven't explained why you think you need to use a `ByRef` parameter - it's possible that you don't really understand pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value semantics when it comes to reference types like `List<T>`. Have a look at [my article](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) on the topic for more information.